# Hide checkout fields ajax by choosing shipping method in Woocommerce

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, checkout

I know this is not a fresh question. I saw such as:

1. [Show or hide checkout fields based on shipping method in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634105/show-or-hide-checkout-fields-based-on-shipping-method-in-woocommerce-3);
2. [Custom checkout field and shipping methods ajax interaction in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668693/custom-checkout-field-and-shipping-methods-ajax-interaction-in-woocommerce-3);

But what I find, on checkout page event handlers are disabled on #shipping_method inputs. And I cant refresh billings checkout fields by `.change() or .click() jQuery`. **This was solved**(see code).

And checkout fields on choosing method shipping also removed, and in array 
`WC()->checkout->get_checkout_fields()` they removed. But when I want to apply order, it notices me that fields, which I removed is required. May be I need to set this fields somewhere else?

My code now looks so:

```
 <?php
        add_action('wp_footer', 'checkout_refresh_fields');
        function checkout_refresh_fields()
        {
            // Only checkout page
            if (is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) :
      ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($) {

               var input = '#shipping_method input';

                function checkInput(value) {
                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'POST',
                        url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                        data: {
                            'action': 'refresh_fields',
                            'input_val': value,
                        },
                        success: function(result) {

                            $('.main-form-checkout').find('.woocommerce-billing-fields').hide()
                            $('.main-form-checkout').append(result);
                            console.log(result); 
                        }
                    });
                }


                $(input).each(function() {
                    console.log($(this).val());
                    if ($(this).val() === 'free_shipping:3' && $(this).is(':checked')) {
                        checkInput($(this).val());
                    }
                })
                $('.form.checkout').on('change', input, function() { --////Now this works
                if(this.checked) {
                 checkInput($(this).val());
                   }
    })


            });
        </script>
<?php
    endif;
}




    add_action('wp_ajax_refresh_fields', 'get_ajax_refresh_fields');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_refresh_fields', 'get_ajax_refresh_fields');
    function get_ajax_refresh_fields()
    {

        if (isset($_POST['input_val']) && $_POST['input_val'] === 'free_shipping:3') {
            add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'theme_remove_billing_checkout_fields');

            function theme_remove_billing_checkout_fields($fields)
            {
                $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
                unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']); 
                unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);

                return $fields;
            }

        }


       WC()->checkout->checkout_form_billing();
       wp_die();
    }
```

Comment: **Ajax is not needed to show/hide checkout fields** based on any behavior as shipping method choice… You just need to: 1) Make the fields that you want to hide optional … 2) add some jQuery code that will show/hide the desired fields (and will make visually the desired fields required) … 3) add a validation process for the required fields (display a message on empty required fields… Just like in [this recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62123477/3730754) or in [those related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3730754%20%5bjQuery%5d%20%5bcheckout%5d%20fields)

Comment: Ok these links are super useful, i need time to analize them, but it is true that event handlers are disabled on that inputs?

Comment: Yes and no, it depends on the fields (you can enable also some event handlers adding simply a class to the desired required fields)… So this is about knowledge and skills...

Comment: I changed code a little and now it works, but fields which I removed still required while apllying order. May be I need to set this fields somewhere else?